# ViewSwitcher not going to previous view

Tags: android, xml, viewswitcher

Hello I am trying to use a `viewswitcher` to go back and forth between and `TextView` and an `EditText`.  My view switches to an `edittext` from a `textview`. But does not switch back. Here is my `xml`:

```
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/noteItemVS"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noteItemTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="textview"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/noteItemEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="edittext"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

        </ViewSwitcher>
```

My code for switching is:

```
protected void switchViews(NoteItem note) {
        ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher)      context.findViewById(R.id.noteItemVS);
        View switchCheck = switcher.getCurrentView();
        if (switchCheck instanceof EditText) {
            EditText l = (EditText)switchCheck ;
            String x = l.getText().toString();
            Log.e("tree",x);
            if (!x.isEmpty()) {
                switcher.showPrevious();
                TextView myTV = (TextView) switcher.findViewById(R.id.noteItemTextView);
                myTV.setText(x);
            }
        }
        ; if (switchCheck instanceof TextView) {
            TextView l = (TextView) switchCheck;
            String x = l.getText().toString();
            switcher.showNext();
            EditText myEditText = (EditText) switcher.findViewById(R.id.noteItemEditText);
            myEditText.setText(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could used also ViewPager, it has also transitions between the pages unlike simple View.Visible and View.Gone implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because interpreter is going through both the if statements and by default latter one is overriding the value of the forment one.
Try below code it will work for sure.

```
protected void switchViews() {
    ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.noteItemVS);
    View switchCheck = switcher.getCurrentView();
    if (switchCheck instanceof EditText) {
        EditText l = (EditText)switchCheck;
        String x = l.getText().toString();
        Log.e("tree",x);
        if (!x.isEmpty()) {
            switcher.showPrevious();
            TextView myTV = (TextView) switcher.findViewById(R.id.noteItemTextView);
            myTV.setText(x);
        }
    }else{
        TextView l = (TextView) switchCheck;
        String x = l.getText().toString();
        switcher.showNext();
        EditText myEditText = (EditText) switcher.findViewById(R.id.noteItemEditText);
        myEditText.setText(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By getting rid of the view switcher i was able to solve the problem. Simply by using View.Gone and View.Visibile

```
protected void switchViews(NoteItem note) {
        if (context.findViewById(R.id.noteItemTextView).getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) context.findViewById(R.id.noteItemEditText);
            String x  = editText.getText().toString();
            editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView textView = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.noteItemTextView);
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            TextView textView = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.noteItemTextView);
            String x  = textView.getText().toString();
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            EditText editText = (EditText) context.findViewById(R.id.noteItemEditText);
            editText.setText(x);
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can still use view switcher if you really want, just try to find out where the problem lies. see the answer